# query on finding numeric function of a generating function

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For the given generating function $A(z)=1/(1-x^3)$ what will be the numeric function..
I can find out for $A(z)=1/(1-x^2)$ but in the first case we get two factor in the denominator $(1-x)$ and $(x^2+x+1)$, now how do we find the numeric function for $1/(x^2+x+1)$?

Comment: What do you mean by numeric function?  Given any $x$ you can compute it.  Are you looking for the terms of the Taylor series at zero?  Are you looking for the partial fraction decomposition?  What is the numeric function for $\frac 1{1-x^2}$?  That example might help understand what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need to factorize the denominator. Let's recall the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*.
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1-y}=1+y+y^2+y^3+\cdots\qquad\qquad  |y|<1
\end{align*}

> We obtain with $y=x^3$
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{1-x^3}=1+x^3+x^6+\cdots\qquad\qquad |x|<1
> \end{align*}
>   and  the coefficients are $1$ if the powers of $x$ are  congruent $0\,\textrm{mod}(3)$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: So the numeric function would be like {1,0,0,1,0,0,1......}?

Comment: Correct. :-) We would rather say the *sequence of coefficients* of the generating function rather than numeric function.

Comment: Thanks :-).  Yes I got it

Comment: @shadowkh: You're welcome!